# How to get the value in an xml section, and if not present set the value as null?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xmlreader, xelement

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EffectFile>
  <Effects>
    <Effect>
      <Type>Blur</Type>
    </Effect>
    <Effect>
      <Type>Sharpen</Type>
    </Effect>
    <Effect>
      <Type>Zoom</Type>
      <Options>
        <Option>88</Option>
        <Option>"miles"</Option>
      </Options>
    </Effect>
  </Effects>
</EffectFile>
```

which I am parsing it like this:

```
xElement.Elements ( "Effects" ).Elements ( "Effect" ).Select (
    e => new Effect (
        ( EffectType ) Enum.Parse ( typeof ( EffectType ), ( string ) e.Elements ( "Type" ).FirstOrDefault ( ) ),
        e.Elements ( "Options" ).Select ( p => ( object ) p.Elements ( "Option" ) ) ) );
```

But with this version every `Effect` gets at least an empty `EffectOptions` value. Is there a way to specify if there is no `Options` section for an `Effect`, the value should be collected as null?

The `Effect` type has a constructor like this:

```
new Effect (EffectType type, EffectOptions options)
```

so just want to pass null to the second parameter if there are no `Options` section.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand, why the code works at all. The cast to `object` at the end of your statement conflicts with the required parameter type `EffectOptions` of your constructor.

Comment: You are right, I left out a detail. What happens is the Effect also has a constructor where the 2nd parameter is IEnumerable<object> options which is passed to EffectOptions which knows how to turn the IEnumerable to its internal options list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Any()` :

```
e.Elements("Options").Any() 
           ? e.Elements("Options").Select (p => (object) p.Elements("Option")) 
           : null )
```

Comment: Thanks, will Any still give me multiple Option values if it exist?

Comment: @Joan: `Any()` just checks whether there is at least one item in the collection, the rest is done by using `? <original clause> : null`, so your collection is used if there is at least one item, otherwise null

Comment: @BrokenGlass: This is a little unrelated but also I now noticed the Option value that's stored seems to be of type System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetElements>d__11. So I think I am not getting the actual value inside the Options tag in the xml file. Do you know how to do that? I thought p.Elements("Option") would give me 88, and "miles" separately.

Comment: Why don't you just change your constructor to accept `IEnumerable<XElement>` instead of `object`? As far as I can see, there is no reason to be that unsafe...

Comment: @Joan - you will have to further parse the XML to do what you described, i.e. `.Select (p =>Elements("Option").Select( o => o.Value).ToList()`

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Thanks, but when I do that, now it stores of type: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String], should it not just print 88 and miles, etc?

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, but do you think it's better to add parsing functionality to the EffectOptions type? Because I thought it would make more sense to do all the parsing inside EffectFile, stuff so after the parsing is done, you get Effect instances correctly initialized with their options. What do you think?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I used .First at the end now the actual value is stored. Is that the right way to do it? I seems like that.

Comment: The second parameter of your `Effects` constructor call should be of type `List<string>` with the code I showed you above.

Comment: Actually since you are parsing `Options` elements it should be `e.Elements("Options").Select (p =>Elements("Option").Select( o => o.Value).ToList()).ToList()` - that means that your parameter is of type `List<List<string>>` - you have a list of string lists, each inner list contains the item collection for one `Options` element.